# Unable to access variable data in Laravel controller function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I am using the [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) project to export data to an Excel file. I am able to generate a file with the correct data using hard coded month and year values, like so

```
 public function month() {

    Excel::create('New file', function($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) {
            $data = new ReportModel;
            $year = (int)2016;
            $month = (int)9;
            $donationData = $data->getDayData($month, $year);
            $sheet->loadView('exports.month', array('donationData' => $donationData));
        });
    })->download('xlsx');
}
```

However, when I try to make the month and year variables, using the following code

```
 public function month($month, $year) {

    Excel::create('New file', function($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) {
            $data = new ReportModel;
            $year = (int)$year;
            $month = (int)$month;
            $donationData = $data->getDayData($month, $year);
            $sheet->loadView('exports.month', array('donationData' => $donationData));
        });
    })->download('xlsx');
}
```

I get the following error

> Access to undeclared static property: App\Http\Controllers\ExportController::$year

I understand this is down to variable scope, but can't get my head round the PHP docs. I have tried

```
$year = (int)self::$year;
```

but am getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inheriting the variables you need access to inside the anonymous function scope.

```
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Something like:

```
Excel::create('New file', function($excel) use ($year, $month) {
    $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) use ($year, $month) {
        $data = new ReportModel;
        $year = (int)$year;
        $month = (int)$month;
        $donationData = $data->getDayData($month, $year);
        $sheet->loadView('exports.month', array('donationData' => $donationData));
    });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: Thanks, @Pistachio worked a charm. Also had to apply the same logic to the $excel->sheet function as well in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in your assumption that it's about variable scope, so you need to "import" the `$year` and `$month` variables in the callback's scope, refactor the call like this and it should work:

```
Excel::create('New file', function($excel) use ($year, $month) { ...
```